# How to override form_errors() from twig Symfony 5.2?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

How to override the form field validation error template in Symfony 5.2?

I have a form like this in twig

```
        {{ form_start(registrationForm) }}
            name:<br />
            {{ form_row(registrationForm.name) }}
            family_name:<br />
            {{ form_row(registrationForm.family_name) }}
            Email:<br />
            {{ form_row(registrationForm.email) }}
            password:<br />
            {{ form_row(registrationForm.password) }}
            <br />
            <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="site-btn">registration</button></div>
        {{ form_end(registrationForm) }}
```

In case of an error in the validation of the email field, this is the layout

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>There is already an account with this email</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" id="registration_form_email" name="registration_form[email]" required="required" maxlength="180" class="register-form-input" autocomplete="off" value="asd">
</div>
```

The problem is that the layout with a form validation error

```
  <ul>
    <li>There is already an account with this email</li>
  </ul>
```

Taken from the standard template symfony, but I want to use my own template when a form field validation fails.

I turned to the documentation for clarifications [this](https://symfony.ru/doc/current/form/form_themes.html) and [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html) but to be honest, it confused me more, I just realized that this form can be stylized somehow in the template, but I didn't understand.

**How to make your own template for displaying field validation error for a form?**

As a result, I want to get such a layout:

```
<div>
  <b>There is already an account with this email</b> <br>
  <input type="text" id="registration_form_email" name="registration_form[email]" required="required" maxlength="180" class="register-form-input" autocomplete="off" value="asd">
</div>
```

Comment: Template of errors are created in `vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form/foundation_5_layout.html.twig` with `{% block errors %}`. So you can override this block with your custom code in a custom template, and in your form template use `{% form_theme form 'forms/extends/errors.html.twig' %}` to override the default block. Look here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html

Comment: but that is, I correctly understood that I need to make a copy of this template to my folder with twig components and style it already?

Comment: For some reason, this template is called differently `vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig`

Comment: `foundation_5_layout.html.twig` extends `form_div_layout.html.twig`, i havn't see form_errors was in `form_div_layout` too, but principle is same. Don't make a copy, create a template "errors.html.twig" by example, create a block `form_errors` with your code you want, and in your form template, call it with `{% form_theme form 'path/to/errors.html.twig' %}`. Is it clearer :) ?
It's just an override of twig blocks

Comment: Thank you so much! I did it, could you please arrange your comments as an answer so that I can mark it  :)

Comment: It's done :) . Happy it was helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foundation_5_layout.html.twig` extends `form_div_layout.html.twig`, i havn't see `form_errors` was in `form_div_layout` too, but principle is same.

Don't make a copy, create a template "errors.html.twig" by example, create a block `form_errors` with your code you want, and in your form template, call it with

```
{% form_theme form 'path/to/errors.html.twig' %}
```

Is it clearer :) ? It's just an override of twig blocks

Answer (score 0):

When using Symfony Forms you can use the form errors function and use HTML to style it to your needs:

TWIG:

```html
{# render only the error messages related to this field #}
{{ form_errors(form.name) }}

{# render any "global" errors not associated to any form field #}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

All you need to know can be found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#reference-forms-twig-errors)